# Why copy/pasting vs copy pastingspecial have a different coding?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is some VBA code

```
Set L060 = Workbooks("L060.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("Variation_week" & WeekFolder & ".xlsm").Worksheets("RM consumption")
SelectionL060 = L060.Cells(L060.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Adestination = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2).Row
L090.Range("A2:M" & SelectionL060).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A" & Adestination)
Workbooks("L060.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Why does not `L060.Range("A2:M" & SelectionL060).Copy _ wsDest.Range("A" & Adestination)` work if you don't add the underscore between `Copy` and `wsDest` ?
Actually if you don't add it, there is a space that automatically appears between `Range` and `("A" & Adestination)` making the code fail.

Whereas `L060.Range("A2:M" & SelectionL060).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & Adestination).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue` works fine without any underscore ?

Comment: It does work without an underscore, you just have to put it on the same line: `L090.Range("A2:M" & SelectionL060).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & Adestination)`

Answer (score 3):

The underscore is just a line continuation character meaning that the next line is actually still part of the initial line. So this:

```
L090.Range("A2:M" & SelectionL060).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A" & Adestination)
```

is the same as this:

```
L090.Range("A2:M" & SelectionL060).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & Adestination)
```

where the destination range is an argument being passed to the `Copy` method. When you use `Copy` and `PasteSpecial` they are actually two **separate** commands, which is why they are on separate lines.